# Django icontains not working on website as it does in the shell

Tags: django, filter

I am trying to filter based on user input with a simple search form. 
Here is the pertinent piece of code from my views.py

```
def search(request):
    error = False
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        if not q:
            error = True
        elif len(q) > 20:
            error = True
        else:
            chemicals = Chemicals.objects.filter(Name__icontains=q)
            return render_to_response('search_results.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('search_form.html',{'error':True})
```

The template

```
<table>
    <th>Barcode</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    {% for chemical in chemicals %}
       {% ifequal chemical.Name q %}
      <tr>
      <td>{{ chemical.Barcode }}     </td>
      <td>{{ chemical.Name }}        </td>
      <td>{{ chemical.Description }} </td>
       {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And the next piece is what I have embedded in search_results.html

An example is that I have a chemical named Nitric Acid. If I put Nitric Acid in the search bar it will display all relevant information for all things with exactly the name Nitric Acid. It is also case sensitive which I thought icontains was not supposed to be. Also searching for Nitric, nitric, Acid, or acid turns up no results which makes me think something is wrong. I used the same command in the shell and it did what I would have expected it to do but it doesn't perform the same on the website. Does anyone have any insight as to why that is the case?
Thanks,

Comment: what is `Name` in `Chemicals` ?

Comment: It is models.CharField(max_length=20)

Comment: Also is it kosher to create a instance (sorry if my lingo is off I'm new to python and django) without deleting or destroying it?

Comment: Can you run this in `./manage.py shell` and get results?

Comment: Yes if I go into the shell and type the following
    from Inventory.models import Chemicals
    q = acid
    chemical = Chemicals.objects.filter(Name__icontains=q)
chemical will return anything that has acid in it.

Comment: Are you using caching? Try replacing `locals()` with `{'chemicals': chemicals}`

Comment: Is there a place to see whether or not I am using a cache?
Just tried your suggestion. No dice still the same behaviour as before.

Comment: if it is *nix, do `ps -ef | grep memcache` or any other caching you are using

Comment: alex 3759  2981  0 13:43 pts/2 00:00:00 grep --color=auto memcache
This is what it returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `ifequal` test:

```
{% ifequal chemical.Name q %}
```

That doesn't show the row unless the chemical name is exactly equal to q.

Comment: Thanks, stupid error on my part. I remember now I was trying to debug a specific entry that was showing up which is why I had that in there. Just goes to show you should take a break every now and then. = D I appreciate it.